# How can I put an html text in a label with xsl?

Tags: xslt

Assume I have an xml document I have a tag containing html text.
I want to display this text with the xsl.
The html tag is `htmlInfo`.

I tought I can put this in a label (in the xsl), but it doesn't work.
What can I do?

Comment: Could you provide sample xml and xsl?

Comment: the xml loo like this
<tableInfo>
<id>1</id>
<htmlInfo><html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'><head ></head> <body><p>xzxzxzxzxz</p>
<p>hghghgh</p>
</body></html></htmlInfo><tableInfo>
ii want to display the content of the htmlInfo in my xsl

Answer (score 1):

You will probably have to encode it into your XML, so it looks like this:

```
<tableInfo> 
    <id>1</id> 
    <htmlInfo>
        &lt;html xmlns='w3.org/1999/xhtml'&gt;&lt;head &gt;&lt;/head&gt; &lt;body&gt;&lt;p&gt;xzxzxzxzxz&lt;/p&gt; &lt;p&gt;hghghgh&lt;/p&gt; &lt;/body&gt;&lt;/html&gt;
    </htmlInfo>
<tableInfo>
```

So all < characters have been replaced with `&lt;` and all > characters have been replaced with `&gt;`. An & should be `&amp;` ... If you're using .NET, don't use String.Replace, but use the System.Xml namespace to correctly build an XmlDocument. It will do the encoding for you.
For example, in VB.Net:

```
Dim stringBuilder As New StringBuilder() 
Dim stringWriter As New StringWriter(stringBuilder) 
Dim xmlTextWriter As New XmlTextWriter(stringWriter) 

xmlTextWriter.WriteStartElement("item") 
xmlTextWriter.WriteAttributeString("id", id.ToString()) 
xmlTextWriter.WriteAttributeString("key", key) 
xmlTextWriter.WriteValue(value) 
xmlTextWriter.WriteEndElement() 

Return stringBuilder.ToString()
```

Then, your XSL should be able to handle it, and if you output the transform to a HTML file for example, the `&lt;` and other stuff should correctly be '<' in the output, and your HTML should be valid.

Comment: i used xmlDocument. but how can i encode the html to xml. and when?

Comment: Which method on XmlDocument are you using to write the htmlInfo tag?

Comment: xsl.Load(xslUrl);
            // Transform the xml
            XPathNavigator navigator = xmlDs.DocumentElement.CreateNavigator();
            StringBuilder sbTransHtml = new StringBuilder();
            StringWriter strwTransHtml = new StringWriter(sbTransHtml);
            XmlTextWriter xmltwTransHtml = new XmlTextWriter(strwTransHtml);
            xsl.Transform(navigator, null, xmltwTransHtml);
            return strwTransHtml.ToString();

Comment: Sorry, I can't seem to get it to work either. If I do, I'll let you know, but if someone else knows, I'd love to hear it.